# Install Virtualbox-4.3 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, virtualbox, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Kindly someone help. I am quite new in Ubuntu. While installing the package, these error messages appear.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-4.3:i386:   
 virtualbox-4.3:i386 depends on libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.20).  
 virtualbox-4.3:i386 depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7).  
 virtualbox-4.3:i386 depends on libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0).  
 virtualbox-4.3:i386 depends on psmisc.  
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-4.3:i386 (--install):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...  
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...  
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'  
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'  
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'  
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'  
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'  
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'  
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'  
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'  
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...  
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...  
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...  
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...  
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 virtualbox-4.3:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download this package:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.16/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.16-95972~Debian~wheezy_i386.deb

Then install, if not installed gdebi:

Open a terminal

run it:

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install gdebi
```

Then your file manager locate the downloaded file

And by right-clicking on it, choose to install with gdebi.

Note: connected to the Internet, gdebi solves all units, if available.